# Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject - ksqlsb with db source connector error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, debezium, ksqldb

I am relatively new to kafka and ksqldb and I am trying to use ksqldb for data pipeline.
I create a source connector to postgres defined like this:

```sql
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR postgres_reader WITH (
    'connector.class' = 'io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector',
    'database.hostname' = 'host.docker.internal',
    'database.port' = '5432',
    'database.user' = 'postgres-user',
    'database.password' = 'postgres-pw',
    'database.dbname' = 'customers',
    'database.server.name' = 'customers',
    'table.whitelist' = 'public.*',
     'value.converter' = 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter',
    'key.converter' = 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter',
    'value.converter.schema.registry.url' = 'http://host.docker.internal:8085',
    'key.converter.schema.registry.url' = 'http://host.docker.internal:8085',
    'transforms' = 'unwrap,createKey,ExtractField',
    'transforms.createKey.type' = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey',
    'transforms.createKey.fields' = 'id',
    'transforms.ExtractField.type' = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key',
    'transforms.ExtractField.field' = 'id',
    'transforms.unwrap.type' = 'io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState',
    'transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones' = 'false',
    'transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode' = 'rewrite',
    'topic.prefix' = 'postgres'
);
```

Now in postges db i have a table called `customers`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.customers
(
    id text NOT NULL,
    name text,
    age integer,
    CONSTRAINT customers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Also I created a stream in ksqlsb:

```sql
CREATE STREAM customers (
    id VARCHAR key,
    name VARCHAR,
    age INTEGER
) WITH (
    kafka_topic = 'postgres.public.customers',
    value_format = 'avro',
    PARTITIONS=1
);
```

When i create the stream as described above it automatically creates the topic and new value and key schema in schema registry which looks like this:

schema-postgres.public.customers-value-v1.avsc:

```
{
  "connect.name": "io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas.KsqlDataSourceSchema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "NAME",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "AGE",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "KsqlDataSourceSchema",
  "namespace": "io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas",
  "type": "record"
}
```

schema-postgres.public.customers-key-v1.avsc:

```
"string"
```

Now when I insert items to the customers table, the connector detects the new data and sends it to the corresponding kafka topic as expected, but I get a schema error in kafka connect:

```
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "postgres.public.customers-value", details: [{errorType:'NAME_MISMATCH', description:'The name of the schema has changed (path '/name')', additionalInfo:'expected: io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas.KsqlDataSourceSchema'}, {errorType:'READER_FIELD_MISSING_DEFAULT_VALUE', description:'The field 'id' at path '/fields/0' in the new schema has no default value and is missing in the old schema', additionalInfo:'id'}, {oldSchemaVersion: 1}, {oldSchema: '{"type":"record","name":"KsqlDataSourceSchema","namespace":"io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas","fields":[{"name":"NAME","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"AGE","type":["null","int"],"default":null}],"connect.name":"io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas.KsqlDataSourceSchema"}'}, {compatibility: 'BACKWARD'}]; error code: 409
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:297)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:367)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:544)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:532)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:490)
```

There are 2 things I don't understand:

1. Why the connector tries to register a new schema uppon producing new message to the topic.
2. If it tries to create a new schema, the schema should be the same because the value includes the correct values specified in the schema.

Comment: Debezium should be creating its own schema. It wouldn't match the ksql namespace that's been set. In other words, try running standalone connect server

Comment: what do you mean bt running a standalone connect server? in this scenario debezium is the one creating the schema, am I wrong?

Comment: I mean run Kafka Connect server externally from ksql. Otherwise, I think you'll need a SetSchemaMetadata transform on the connector config

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a good solution, but at the end I just used `JSON` format instead of `avro` on the stream, and used Json key and value converter on the connector.

this is the final configurations:

ksql stream creation - notice the `value_format = 'JSON'`:

```sql
CREATE STREAM customers (
    id VARCHAR key,
    name VARCHAR,
    age INTEGER
) WITH (
    kafka_topic = 'postgres.public.customers',
    value_format = 'JSON',
    PARTITIONS=1
);
```

connector creation - notice `JsonConverter` usage:

```sql
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR postgres_reader WITH (
  'connector.class' = 'io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector',
  'database.hostname' = 'host.docker.internal',
  'database.port' = '5432',
  'database.user' = 'postgres-user',
  'database.password' = 'postgres-pw',
  'database.dbname' = 'customers',
  'database.server.name' = 'customers',
  'table.whitelist' = 'public.*',
  'transforms' = 'unwrap,extractField',
  'transforms.unwrap.type' = 'io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState',
  'transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones' = 'false',
  'transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode' = 'rewrite',
  'transforms.extractField.type' = 
  'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key',
  'transforms.extractField.field' = 'id',
  'value.converter' = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
  'value.converter.schemas.enable' = 'false',
  'topic.prefix' = 'postgres'
);
```